# Eclipse plugin that shows the META-INF of a jar library

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, jar

Currently in eclipse when you open a library jar, it shows all the packages and classes, but if you want to see the META-INF content (e.g. manifest.mf), you have to open the file externally (e.g. using winrar)

Is there a simple way buit-in in eclipse to do so, or a plugin that does this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use the Project Explorer view (part of Eclipse Java EE) instead of the Package Explorer view, and view everything inside the jar, including properties files, xmls, etc.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Jar-Plug will do the trick

http://jar-plug.sourceforge.net/

Comment: I think that I've already tried it, I can't remember what caused me to remove it. Is this really the only one?

Answer (score 0):

Under Linux, I simply associate (inside Eclipse) the `jar` extension with the `file-roller` application, which lets you browse the innards of packed files. Works fine for me. This doesn't directly display META-INF, of course, but I can go there and click on the file (e.g. manifest.mf). This is very convenient.

Under Windows, I suppose you could similarly link out to something like `7Zip`. I have no experience to contribute there, alas.